# What happens when a data.frame gets new columns?

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe, names

It seems like `data.frames` inherit the colnames of matrices if a matrix is added to them by the `[` function. Example:

```
blob <- matrix(11:20, ncol = 1, dimnames = list(NULL, "BLOB"))
foo <- data.frame(FOO = 201:210)

dat <- data.frame(id = 1:10)

dat[, "new1"] <- blob 
dat[, "new2"] <- foo
```

If I now look on `dat`, it shows me

```
id BLOB new2
1   11  201
2   12  202
3   13  203
...
```

So not the expected `"new1"` is shown, but `"BLOB"`; even if the `colnames(dat)` are `"id"`, `"new1"` and `"new2"`. Furthermore `"BLOB"` is nowhere found in `attributes(dat)` and `dat[, "BLOB"]` gives the "undefined columns selected"-error.
Two questions:

1. why does `dat` shows `"BLOB"` and not `"new1"` in this case?
2. How can I change `dat` in a way that it shows `"new1"` instead of `"BLOB"`?

Answer (score 2):

Assigning a whole matrix to a column of a data.frame creates a very odd object. If you look at the structure of `dat` you'll see

```
'data.frame':   10 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ id  : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
 $ new1: int [1:10, 1] 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : NULL
  .. ..$ : chr "BLOB"
 $ new2: int  201 202 203 204 205 206 207 208 209 210
```

So you've added a column that is still a matrix. And you can see that the embded matrix retained the column name "BLOB". It would be safer to just assign a column of the matrix to the column of the data.frame with

```
dat[, "new1"] <- blob[,1]
```

The reason this happens that `blob` could have more than one column. If you only assign it to "new1" there where should those other columns go? So it embeds the entire matrix within the column.

You can expanded embeded matrixes with

```
do.call("cbind.data.frame", dat)
```

which would keep the "BLOB" column name but it would now be a "normal" data.frame so "BLOB" would be listed in the `colnames()`

When R print a data.frame with an embed matrix, normally it prefixes the data.frame column name before the matrix column names, but when there is only one column, it uses just the matrix column name (which admittedly can be confusing).  Observe:

```
mm<-matrix(1:9+10, nrow=3, dimnames=list(NULL, c("m1","m2","m3")))
data.frame(a=1:3, b = mm, c=letters[1:3])
#   a b.m1 b.m2 b.m3 c
# 1 1   11   14   17 a
# 2 2   12   15   18 b
# 3 3   13   16   19 c
data.frame(a=1:3, b = mm[,1, drop=FALSE], c=letters[1:3])
#   a m1 c
# 1 1 11 a
# 2 2 12 b
# 3 3 13 c
```

Long story short: don't put a matrix in a data.frame.

Comment: Probably worth mentioning that assigning a `data.frame` like `foo` to a full column is similarly risky. `<- foo[[1]]` or `<- foo[, 1]` would be nicely defensive.

Comment: @MrFlick, thank you for the answer so far. Can you explain (or give a reference) to what embedded matrices are (including their purpose) and how R handle those?